# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for _destroy doesnt work unless associations are already loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

Rails 3.0.5 doesn't seem to destroy children of a parent object using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` unless the children are loaded. Does anyone know if this is by design?  It seems a bit odd to me.  Here's the setup.

```
class Foo < AR
  has_many :bars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Bar < AR
  belongs_to :foo
end

# create a Foo with 5 bars (ie. Foo.create :bars_attributes => ... )
# then fetch a foo, without its bars

f = Foo.find(1)
f.update_attributes("bars_attributes" => {"id" => "1", "_destroy" => "1"})
Foo.find(1).bars.length   # => 5

f = Foo.find(1, :include => :bars)
f.update_attributes("bars_attributes" => {"id" => "1", "_destroy" => "1"})
Foo.find(1).bars.length   # => 4
```

Comment: you mean `accepts_nested_attributes_for :barS, :allow_destroy => true`

Comment: sorry ya, missed the `s`, not sure what your subsequent comments mean?

Comment: I think @fl00r is saying that it works for him on 3.0.3 and 3.0.5.

Comment: I have this "bug" as well in Rails 3.0.6

Comment: I've seen this behaviour in Rails 2.3.8.

Comment: I'm getting a very similar problem to this is 3.1.0 and 3.1.3. Causing problems with removing nested fields from a form. Did you get to the bottom of this? It feels like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo#bars` is a `has_many` so it will be expecting more than 1 thing, which means an `Array`. Try passing an `Array` of `Hash` like so:

```
f = Foo.find(1, :include => :bars)
f.update_attributes("bars_attributes" => [{"id" => "1", "_destroy" => "1"})]
```